# tail -f does not seem to work in the shell when file is being populated through file.write()

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to daemonize a python script that currently runs in the foreground. However, I still need to be able to see its output which it currently dumps to stdout.

So I am using the following piece of code which generates a unique file name in /tmp and then it assigns sys.stdout to this new file. All subsequent calls to 'print' are then redirected to this log file.

```
import uuid
outfile = open('/tmp/outfile-' + str(uuid.uuid4()), 'w')
outfile.write("Log file for daemon script...\n")
sys.stdout=outfile

# Rest of script uses print statements to dump information into the /tmp file
.
.
.
```

The problem I am facing is that, when I `tail -f` the file created in /tmp, I don't see any output. However, once I kill my daemon process, output is visible in the /tmp logfile, because python flushes out the file data.

I want to monitor the /tmp log file in realtime, hence it would be great if somehow, the output can be made visible in realtime.

One solution that I have tried was trying to use unbeffered IO, but that didn't help either.

Comment: does sys.stdout.flush() work?

Comment: flush() cannot help with redirected stdout

Comment: @Stuart, how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: He'd need to flush after every "print" throughout the code base (where the file handle is most likely unavailable). A singleton could be created to encapsulate all this, if he is able to change all the instances of "print" to use the replacement.

Answer (score 4):

Try harder to use unbuffered I/O.  The problem is almost certainly that your output is buffered.

Opening the file like this should work:

```
outfile = open(name, 'w', 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT for your answer! I tried that and it worked. However, using 'python -u' was not working for unbuffered IO, so I was not sure if using 0 as buffer size would work within the code.